# Simple ESAPI Directory Path Validation Example Not Working

Tags: java, exception, esapi

I have build a ESAPITestValidator class as follows :

```
public class ESAPITestValidator {

Validator instance = ESAPI.validator();
ValidationErrorList errors = new ValidationErrorList();
File parent = null;
String path = new String("");
boolean status = false;
public boolean testGetValidDirectoryPath(String inputPath,String context)  
 {
     try
     {
        parent = new File(inputPath).getParentFile().getCanonicalFile();
        //String parent = ESAPI.securityConfiguration().getResourceFile("ESAPI.properties").getParentFile().getCanonicalPath();
        path = instance.getValidDirectoryPath(context, inputPath, parent, true, errors);
        status = true;
        return status;
     }catch(Exception exception)
     {
         exception.printStackTrace();
         status= false;  
     }
     return status;
 }

}
```

Now I am Trying to invoke the testGetValidDirectoryPath() from a main class as follows :

```
public class HelloWorld {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ESAPITestValidator obj =  new ESAPITestValidator();
    if ( obj.testGetValidDirectoryPath("C:\\Users\\1730176\\Downloads","C:\\Users") )
      System.out.println("Success");
    else
      System.out.println("Failure");        
 }

}
```

I have also Uploaded the ESAPI.properties and Validation.properties in the same Source folder as the main and validator class.
But I am getting the following exception :

```
System property [org.owasp.esapi.opsteam] is not set
System property [org.owasp.esapi.devteam] is not set
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: 
D:\Arindam_Workspace\ESAPI_Workspace\ESAPIProofOfConcept\ESAPI.properties
Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: 
.esapi\ESAPI.properties
Found in 'user.home' directory: C:\Users\1730176\esapi\ESAPI.properties
Loaded 'ESAPI.properties' properties file
SecurityConfiguration for Validator.ConfigurationFile.MultiValued not found 
in ESAPI.properties. Using default: false
Attempting to load validation.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load validation.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: 
D:\Arindam_Workspace\ESAPI_Workspace\ESAPIProofOfConcept\
validation.properties
Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: 
.esapi\validation.properties
Found in 'user.home' directory: C:\Users\1730176\esapi\validation.properties
Loaded 'validation.properties' properties file
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2670)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1603)
at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:77)
at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.validator(ESAPI.java:191)
at main.utility.ESAPITestValidator.<init>(ESAPITestValidator.java:20)
at main.core.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 8 more
```

Can anyone sujjest What I have done worng or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM is looking for the `javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest` class, and you haven't loaded it into the classpath.  You will need to include an implementation of the [java servlet API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api) on the classpath.  Keep in mind that ESAPI is a web-based library and you will probably have an easier time testing if you clone the actual esapi-java-legacy project and work with the unit tests there.